# event between main form and child control

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

Hi I have main form in which I am displaying user controls like ManageDepartment. I have few buttons like RESET in main form.

I want to have event in ManageDepartment to reset controls.

When user clicks on Reset Button on main form, the button should call the reset event on displayed control i.e. ManageDepartment

Can any one suggest me how can I achieve this?

If this is duplicate question, please direct me to original question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call an event.  If the user control has a `Reset` event then that event would get raised by that control.

It sounds more like what you need is a `Reset` method on the user control.  You would handle the `Click` event of the `Button` on the form and call the `Reset` method of the control.  In that method you would do as required to reset the control, e.g. call `Clear` on each `TextBox`.